# javascriptからjavaのDate型への変換

Tags: javascript, java

パラメータとして、javascriptから渡された値(Date型)をjavaのDate(java.util.Date)型に変換したいです。

javascript側でjavaのDate(java.util.Date)に変換するか、javascriptでは変換せずに、java側で受け取った後に変換するかどちらの方法でもかまいません。

ご教示いただけますと幸いです。

Comment: どういう環境で両言語を使う場合の話でしょうか? アプレット? JSP? Rhino? Nashorn?

Comment: 初心者で、の理解が難しいのですが、
EXTJSをつかって、日付をフォームに入力した際にフォームに入力されたパラメータがリクエストにはjs側の日付型でパラメータが渡され、Javaで受け取る際に、jsのDate型をJavaの日付型に変更する必要があります。

Comment: フロント（画面）をEXTJSが担当して、バック（サーバロジック）側をJavaでということでしょうか？その場合、サーバ側をJavaの何を使って実装しているのか開示しないとどなたも回答できません。たとえばJAX-RS使ってとかサーバーロジックはSpringBootでとか、Servletで生でやるのなら、PostなりGet時に渡してくるデータをパースすればいいだけですが、まさか今どきそんなことしないと思いますし。。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

現在試されている実装のコード片(サーバサイド/クライアントサイド)でも貼り付けてもらえると、何がやりたいのか他の方が理解する助けになるかと思います。

可能性の一例として下記回答を付記します。
これに対するコメント(ここはそのような機能は使っておらず…だ、この点はその通りだ、など)も同様に他の方が理解する助けになるかと思います。

---

[ExtJSのform](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/classic/Ext.form.Basic.html)から日付型フィールド(`xtype: 'datefield'`)入力値をsubmitする場合ですと、単に`format`で指定した通りに整形された文字列として渡るので、JavaScriptの`Date`型は一切登場しません。
例えば

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'datefield',
    format: 'Y-m-d',
    fieldLabel: 'Field',
    name: 'theField'
}],
```

と指定した場合、サーバにわたるのは `2019-05-05` という文字列です。

サーバサイドでは、この文字列を`Date`型にパースすることになるはずです([`DateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/12/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DateFormat.html)あるいは[`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/12/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)が利用可能でしょう)。

```
final String date = req.getParameter("theField");
result = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(date);
```

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。
勉強時に起こったもの等であれば、コードを貼ることは可能かと思いますが、会社のコードを公開はできないと思うのですが、通常皆様どのように対応されていらっしゃるのでしょうか。

回答につきましても参考にさせていただきます。

Comment: [ヘルプセンター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)より: "**一から作り直す** プログラムを新規作成し、問題を再現するのに必要な部分のみを追加していきます。コードが大規模で、関連箇所を特定できそうであれば、最初から作り直した方が早いケースがあります。実際のコードを（契約上、倫理上の理由から）公開できない場合にも有効な方法です。"

Comment: やはりサンプルコードを用意するのがいいのですね。ありがとうございます。